# How to enable Analyze ribbon in WFFM (Sitecore)?

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I have an issue in my Web Form for Marketers form, My Analyze ribbon (Both Properties and Profiles) is disabled. Is there anything in Settings that I should do in order to enable the Analyze ribbon?

Also, My Form Reports display my Email Address (one of my WFFM field) value hidden for all the entries. How to make them display?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause.

We have used customized WFFM filed for Email address, so there was a piece of code to hide in Result.

I had to remove the piece and start inserting new records, it works.

Email address was tagged between schidden.

Code - secure:{0}